# How to launch DialogFragment from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, dialogfragment

Im trying to launch my dialogfragment from Broadcast Receiver, if the App is open the dialog work propertly but if the app is in background when my Broadcast Receiver launch the dialog, my crash. Any help?

DialogFragment.java

```js
public class AlarmDialogPopUp extends DialogFragment
{



    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Dialog dialog = null;
    private Button btnOK;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),R.raw.alarmsound);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle id)
    {

        mediaPlayer.start();
        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alarm_dialog);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        btnOK = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDialogOK);
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                AlarmDialogPopUp.this.dismiss();
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }


}
```

BroadCastReceiver.java

```js
 private void registerBatteryLevelReceiver(Context ctx) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        ctx.registerReceiver(battery_receiver, filter);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver battery_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        
        {
            
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            AlarmDialogPopUp editNameDialog = new AlarmDialogPopUp();
            editNameDialog.show(fm, MainActivity.kMainFragment);

        }
    };
```

Comment: You can't run dialog while user is in other application and your app is in background. All you can do is to check where app crashes, probably null exception in fragment manager or activity, and handle it to show dialog only if it is non-null.

Comment: It is curious you say that because I tried to create an activity instead of dialogfragment and if it works. So what possibilities I have to create an app that shows an alarm and pop up to cancel the alarm? Thank for your help

Comment: You can show notification. When user is in other app he will still receive notification, and you can even set buttons on notifications, or just make click on notification go to your activity. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html